# Why is my alert dialog crashing my app the second time it appears?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an alert dialog that I'm calling when the user clicks the button with the correct answer for my game. The first time it is called the alert appears fine on the screen, however if the user gets the answer right a second time the app will crash and tell me "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

```
//this is my alert
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
builder.setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout, null))

//this is the button being clicked
btnClickMe1.setOnClickListener {
        if (correctAnswer == 1) {
            score++
            updateUI()
            builder.show()
        }
        updateUI()
    }
```

I just want the alert to appear as many times as needed without crashing the app

Comment: Move your builder inside the click listener.

Comment: what is in your updateUI method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AlertDialog initialisation part is called only one time and your listener called every time you pressed that button . so it is causing that error.

You have to initialise your dialog every time you click on button. so solution would be .

```
//this is the button being clicked
btnClickMe1.setOnClickListener {
        if (correctAnswer == 1) {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout, null))

            score++
            updateUI()
            builder.show()
        }
        updateUI()
    }
```

Comment: You have solved my problem. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @RyanMoye i'm glad i helped you.